# Не работают две функции одновременно в Discord боте

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я хочу, что бы мой бот одновременно выполнял функции в **main()** вместе с функцией **asks()**.

```
import disnake
import threading
from disnake.ext import commands
from threading import Thread

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=disnake.Intents.all())
client = disnake.Client()

ask_ls = ['Что выберете:', '1. Написать сообщение.', '2.Выйти']
ls_write = ['1']
ls_exit = ['2']

async def asks():  # пишет сообщение от лица бота в чат через консоль
    print('\n'.join(ask_ls))
    for ask in ask_ls:
        choose = input()
        if choose in ls_write:
            #try:
            channel = await bot.get_channel(int(input("ID Канала: ")))
            msg = input('Ваше сообщение: ')
            await channel.send(msg)
            #await channel.send(content=input("Ваше сообщение: "))
            #except:
                #return asks()
        elif choose in ls_exit:
            exit()
        else:
            return await asks()

def between_callback():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(asks())
    loop.close()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')
 
def main():
    print('Много функций')

th1 = Thread(target=main).start()
th2 = Thread(target=between_callback).start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Ошибки:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4 (between_callback):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\
threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\
threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\main.py", line 88, in 
between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(asks())
  File "C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\
asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\main.py", line 75, in asks
    await channel.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\disnake\abc.py", line 1655, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\disnake\http.py", line 344, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as 
response:
  File "C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 467, in _request
    with timer:
  File "C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 701, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Как мне избежать эти ошибку?

Comment: Попробуйте что-то [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59645689/12333689).

Comment: @jillstr Я попробовал всё что там было и пишет такую же ошибку(((( Не помогло!

Comment: Ещё у вас в коде `return asks()`, перед `asks()` нужно написать `await`

Comment: @jillstr Всё почти сработало, ошибки нету, НО когда я начинаю писать ID канала или выбираю выйти из программы, то ничего не происходит и заново начинается функцию asks()

Comment: а где вы пишете сообщение? В консоли или в чате?

Comment: Также попробуйте заменить `await bot.fetch_channel()` на `bot.get_channel()`. Аргументом в `get_channel()` является ID канала, ID должно быть числом, а не строкой.

Comment: @jillstr Пишу сообщение в консоли. Я  по пробовал заменить ```fetch_channel``` на ```get_channel``` но пишет ошибку на этапе отправки ID, ```get_channel``` возвращает значение None, а ```fetch``` не выдаёт ошибку. То что вы мне скинул ранее у меня почти заработало(**Добавил функцию between_callback(), Добавил всё это в Thread**) Только я остановился на этапе отправки сообщения в чат, пишет ошибку: ```TypeError: coroutine.send() takes no keyword arguments``` **Ссылаются на строку отправки сообщения**. Ещё есть ошибка которая тоже ссылается(```between_callback loop.run_until_complete(asks())```)

Comment: А для ввода ID канала вы использовали `int(input())`?. Если данный метод возвращает `None`, тут два варианта, либо вы неправильно передаёте значение, либо бот не находится в гильдии. Просто в документации написано, что желательно использовать метод `get_channel()` для взаимодействия с каналами. Также попробуйте сообщение в канал вывести в отдельную переменную, например `msg = input()`, а для отправки использовать `await channel.send(msg)`.

Comment: @jillstr Я всё сделал как вы сказали, но выходят такие ошибки( Если что я поменял код в вопросе и добавил ошибки, которые выходят!!

Comment: Возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74948117/12333689) поможет